# Possible to make more iteration than element count?

Tags: jsrender

recently I started to use jsrender, my client needs a table with 5 rows, if there're only 3 data items, the table will be filled with 3 rows and leave the other 2 blank.

when I use jsrender, I used template like following,

```
<script id="TmpOperation" type="text/x-jsrender">
 <tr>
  <td>{{:name}}</td>
 </tr>
</script>
```

My Problem is, it will not generate 5 rows if the data item is less than 5, how can I generate blank table rows ?

=====update

for my data:

```
data=[
    {name:'aaa'}, 
    {name:'bbb'}, 
    {name:'ccc'}
]
```

code to render:

```
var template = $.templates("#TmpOperation");

var html = template.render(data);

$("#tbody_report").html(html);
```

html code:

```
        <table >
            <tbody id="tbody_report">

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Now that there's only 3 elements in it, there will be a table with 3 rows, but I need 5 rows ( 3 rows filled and other 2 blank), thanks.

Comment: We'd have to see the code which generates the data items to be able to comment on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add some blank objects to the end of your `data` array, either on the server-side or the client side. Here's some JavaScript that will work after you've retrieved your `data` and before you've passed it to your template.

```
for (var i = 5 - data.length; i > 0; i--) { 
    data.push({name: ''});
}
```

Comment: It might be necessary to put *something* in there, maybe an `&nbsp;` or `&#8203;` (a zero-width space) to keep the table cells consistent.